# Confusion with "xkeyval" and "newcommand": Better Way to Use with "lstinputlisting"

Tags: listings, xkeyval

I've written this command to get me "snippets" of code:

```
\newcommand\codesnippetsnippet[3]{
\immediate\write18{find ../../../.. -name '#1' -print | grep #2 | xargs cat > ./listingwithoutcomments}

\lstinputlisting[autogobble=true,linerange=#3,rangeprefix=//---,includerangemarker=false,language=mycodelanguage,frame=single]{./listingwithoutcomments}

\immediate\write18{rm -f -- 'listingwithoutcomments'}
}
```

It's used like this:

```
\codesnippet{option1}{option2}{option3}
```

More fully:

```
\codesnippet{thisissomecode.codefile}{thisisagrepfilter}{thisisalinerangemarker}
```

The motivation behind this is basically because I'm trying to use `lstinputlisting` to find files recursively within a (Linux) directory structure, and I'm using `find` from Bash to get around the fact that it can't. At least, I don't believe it can.

The thing is that I suspect this is not the best way to do this, but it does work in the sense that it does what I want. I'm not a huge fan of the way that I use three separate options, though, and that's what I really want to avoid if possible, but I'm really struggling to make sense of how I'd use `xkeyval` to achieve this, which I think is my best bet. What I would really like, for example, is to be able to use `codesnippet` like this:

```
\codesnippet[filename=,grepfilter=,linerangemarker=}
```

... or even better, actually use linerange per the lstinputlisting option, but I suspect this probably isn't possible:

```
\codesnippet[filename=,grepfilter=,linerange=}
```

I think my trouble stems from the fact that I'm embedding a command (`lstinputlisting`) inside my "newcommand", and since I haven't had any luck experimenting with `xkeyval` I just want to ask if anyone could:

A. Help me get on the right track understanding how I would use `xkeyval` to come up with something like this:

```
\codesnippet[filename=,grepfilter=,linerangemarker=}
```

B. Help me understand whether the use of `lstinputlisting` may be complicating things, as it has its own options

C. (Bonus) Help me understand whether there is a better way of doing this altogether, and what else I may be doing wrong ... e.g. is there a way to get `lstinputlisting` to find files recursively without using `find` altogether?

Any help would as always be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can certainly do this using xkeyval. You'd need to declare some options (maybe just`filter` and `marker`  so the usage is `\codesnippet[filter=foo,marker=bar]{filename}`) and then based on the options given construct the `\write18` command and decide what options to pass to `\lstinputlisting`. There's no problem with using `\lstinputlisting` as you're doing it that I can see.

Comment: tex can't so easily cat the files but it could input a file of name `#1` from some arbitrarily deep directory without needing shell escape.  Just as `article.cls` can be input from anywhere